# QProcess Wrong Behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt5.7

My application runs different bash files when i run my application under QTCreator everything works fine but when i run my application directly i cant read the QProcess output . even when i run my application via Terminal it works fine , so where is the problem ? 
i'm using `QT 5.7 / OSX Platform`
here is my code

```
        QProcess proc ;
    proc.start(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/check.sh");
    proc.waitForFinished();
    QString output = QString(proc.readAll());
    qDebug() << output ;
```

Comment: what you mean running application directly? is check.sh executed when you running application?

Comment: Where do you expect the process output to appear? If you run an application by double clicking on Finder, you will not see stderr or stdout anywhere, i.e. you will not see `qDebug()` output anywhere.

Comment: I know i've use Qmessagebox for showing the output but the code provided here is part of my code just for showing how i read the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possibilities you should investigate

- Can you confirm that scripts are running though when you run it standalone?
- QProcess always was a little skittish about creating processes when supplied scripts, depending on platform. Does script have shebang in it? Does it match the shell you're running your program from? You may need to create process based on shell, supplying script's file name as a parameter.
- QProcess::readAll() May return nothing if output buffer wasn't flushed by the process. Outputting EOL at end would force the flush.

Comment: I don't know why but it works when i add the bin and sbin paths through qputenv manually

Comment: You could also try `QProcess::setProcessEnvironment()` if you don't want to change your own programs environment.

Comment: @Koorosh Ghorbani what is written in script? #!bash ? or #!/bin/bash ? Former wouldn't work unless there is that folder in environment. Also, symbol links may be an issue